# How can I get a list of groups in linux?

Tags: linux, permissions

In linux I want to see all the user groups. How can I do this? Am I understanding the concept of groups correctly?

Comment: "Am I understanding the concept of groups correctly?" - How do you expect us to know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F: '{print "group name ", $1, " groupid ", $3}' /etc/group
```

Comment: I see too that I can just `cat /etc/group` and get it that way. Thank you.

Comment: That might not work if `/etc/nsswitch.conf` configures the system to use LDAP or NIS for groups.

Comment: @Basile - correct.  Given the nature of the question I made some assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

`cat /etc/group |cut -d: -f1` will give you a list of all groups. `groups` will give you a list of all groups your user is in.

Answer (score 0):

You can also type mkgroup with no parameters at the command line, or

```
mkgroup --help
```

for more details.